# pandas MultiIndex is_unique returns False on unique indices

Tags: python, pandas

The attribute is_unique returns False on rows of my DataFrame although these should be unique. What is going on?

This works as expected:

```
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B','C'], ['spam', 'foo'], [2019,2020]])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=multi_index, columns=['Value'])
df.index.is_unique # returns True as expected
```

But with my data it does not: I get False on every row in the dataframe.

```
df['unique'] = df.index.is_unique # returns False on all rows
df['unique'].sum() # returns 0
```

But if I select any row using a unique combination of index keys just one row is returned although the column 'Unique' shows False on this one row:

```
df.sort_index(inplace=True) # to avoid indexing.py:1494: PerformanceWarning
df.loc[('00AO00', '2019-2020', 1319), 'Unique'] # returns one row with value False
```

The DataFrame with my data is shared in [this OneDrive folder](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlNIYisf3zAHs898tnxSdKwTYzWLPg?e=ILhrOt). (I just did df.to_pickle('df.pkl') ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if understand, but if want check all duplicated `MultiIndex` values use [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` for all dupes and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.read_pickle('df.pkl')
print (df[df.index.duplicated(keep=False)])
                                              Totaal  unique
Vestigingsnummer Jaar      Postcode leerling                
00AZ00           2016-2017 Onbekend                1   False
                           Onbekend                2   False
00BW00           2016-2017 Onbekend                2   False
                           Onbekend                7   False
                 2017-2018 Onbekend                4   False
                                             ...     ...
31BK00           2019-2020 Onbekend               12   False
31FM00           2018-2019 Onbekend                2   False
                           Onbekend                1   False
31LK00           2019-2020 Onbekend                1   False
                           Onbekend                1   False

[5057 rows x 2 columns]
```

If remove duplicated values remove `keep=False`, so is used default `keep='first'`, inverse mask and filter - then get unique `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = df[~df.index.duplicated()]
print (df1.index.is_unique)
True
```

Comment: O, wow, thank you! I interpreted the is_unique attribute at row level but it of course applies to the df as a whole! I should indeed have used the .duplicated check! This fully explains it, thank you so much! ('Onbekend' means unknown in Dutch which explains that there are duplicates in the df).